# SDL program not working correctly after alll correct line's in linux

Tags: sdl-2

I have write SDL code in vscode to pop the window and when i 
    compile it using `g++ file.cpp -lSDL2` no error was thier but 
    when i run it by 
    "./a.out" it does not show any thing to me.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<SDL2/SDL.h>

    using namespace std;

    // main function
    int main( int argc, char *args[] )
    {
    // Initialize SDL video sub system        
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
        cout << endl << SDL_GetError();

    // create a window and pop it        
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Linux", 100, 100, 700, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    // wait for 6 second    
    SDL_Delay(6000);
        return 0;
   }


//it should pop a window
```

Comment: Your code correctly shows window in my latest Arch Linux . Check that return value of `SDL_CreateWindow()` is not `NULL` and if so, maybe `SDL_GetError()` would help. Or window might be already shown somewhere.

Comment: It works when I use SDL_UpdateWindowSurface();